# Floquet multipliers of $x'=f(t)A_ox$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, periodic-functions

I am trying to find the Floquet multipliers of $x'=f(t)A_ox$ where f(t) is a scalar T-periodic function and $A_o$ is a constant matrix with real distinct eigenvalues.

I know that the floquet multipliers are the eigenvalues of L where the fundamental matrix $X(t)=e^{Lt}$.

I guess my first problem is that I don't know how to find the fundamental matrix of $x'=f(t)A_ox$. It doesn't fit any of the standard forms I have learned.

Thanks for any help you can give.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a time-varying linear system of the form
$$\dot{x}=A(t)x$$
with the special structure $$A(t):=f(t)A_0$$
and $f(t)$ a $T$-periodic function. Due to the commutativity property $$A(t)A(s)=A(s)A(t)$$
the fundamendal matrix which is given by the [Peano-Baker series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State-transition_matrix) takes the special form
$$\Phi(t,t_0)=\exp\left(\int_{t_0}^tf(s)A_0ds\right)$$
For a $T$-periodic $A(t)$ the Floquet multipliers are the eigenvalues of the matrix
$\Phi(T,0)$ and since the eigenvalues of $A_0$ are distinct the multipliers are
$$\exp\left(\lambda_i(A_0)\int_0^Tf(s)ds\right)$$ 
with $\lambda_i(A_0)$ the $i$-th eigenvalue of $A_0$.